# Xcode Webview Open Url

Tags: xcode, url, webview, launch

I'm trying to develop a web browser that will display a website after the launch .
I already red the articles and with i cant seem to get it to work with this code .

```
NSURL*url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
NSURLRequest*request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[[webview mainFrame] loadRequest:request];
```

I'm using the cocoa and the Webkit Framework .

Comment: What exactly is not working? Have you added a `WebView` in your `xib` and connected it to your `webview` outlet? Also, where are you trying to execute the above snippet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)notification{
    NSString *urlText = @"http://google.com";
    [[myWebView mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlText]]];
    return;
}
```

if that doesn't work, try this:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib{
    NSString *urlText = @"http://google.com";
    [[myWebView mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlText]]];
    return;
}
```

Good luck! tell me if this works!

Answer (score 0):

Use -

```
[webview loadRequest:request];
```